# Continue MYSQL output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join, fetch

I have a select on a database, like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("                 
SELECT dat_eb_registrants.id, dat_eb_registrants.first_name,  
    dat_eb_registrants.last_name, dat_eb_registrants.email, dat_eb_registrants.comment,   
    dat_eb_registrants.amount, dat_eb_registrants.published,   
    dat_eb_registrants.transaction_id, dat_eb_registrants.register_date,   
    dat_eb_field_values.field_value   
FROM dat_eb_registrants LEFT JOIN dat_eb_field_values 
  ON dat_eb_registrants.id=dat_eb_field_values.registrant_id
WHERE dat_eb_field_values.field_id='53' AND `event_id` >= 20 AND `event_id` <= 25
ORDER BY $sort $ascdsc
");
```

and it gets diplayed in a html table like so:
    echo " 
     
     ID 
     First name  
     Last name 
     Email 
     Comment 
     Value1 
     Value2 
     Value3 
    ";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row[?] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[?] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

}

Now, the first 4 values are being displayed correctly, just like the 5th one, but how about the 6th and the 7th one? they are not being called by MYSQL because `dat_eb_field_values.field_value` is only called one time, and is assigned the value WHERE dat_eb_field_values.field_id='53

How can i complete the table with the other values in the database?

Thanks in advance, Laurent

Comment: would calling 'dat_eb_field_values.field_id='53' OR`event_id` >= 20 ' be helpful instead of usin 'AND'. or should put some table data here fo us to understand you more??

Comment: Looks like i forgot, i edited it!

Comment: `event_id` >= 20 has nothing to do with the field values, it's just used to sort.

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are being formally deprecated from PHP. They have been considered obsolete and insecure for years, but now they're definitely bad practice to use them. If at all possible, you should switch to using the `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to load multiple values for each person. These values are in multiple rows in a separate table.

You'll need to use a `GROUP BY` clause. `JOIN` the registrants table with the values table just like you do now, and after the `WHERE` clause, `GROUP BY` the registrant's id. And of course, don't restrict the `WHERE` to a certain value's ID, because then you won't get any other values. Finally, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get all the value rows into a single result value, delimited by `,`. You can change this to be delimited by `</td><td>` to make it easier to put into your table.

```
SELECT registrants.name, GROUP_CONCAT(values.value SEPARATOR '</td><td>')
FROM registrants
LEFT JOIN values USING (registrant_id)
WHERE ...
GROUP BY registrant_id
```

Comment: is it simply "GROUP BY dat_eb_registrants.id" ?

Comment: and removing the "dat_eb_field_values.field_id='53'"

Comment: Yes, and changing the value in the `SELECT` clause by the `GROUP_CONCAT` thing. That way, you'll combine all value rows into 1 result (see my updated answer).

Comment: okay, now this is what i have: SELECT dat_eb_registrants.id, dat_eb_registrants.first_name, dat_eb_registrants.last_name, dat_eb_registrants.email, dat_eb_registrants.comment, dat_eb_registrants.amount, dat_eb_registrants.published, dat_eb_registrants.transaction_id, dat_eb_registrants.register_date, GROUP_CONCAT(dat_eb_field_values.field_value SEPARATOR '</td><td>') 
FROM dat_eb_registrants LEFT JOIN dat_eb_field_values ON dat_eb_registrants.id=dat_eb_field_values.registrant_id
WHERE `event_id` >= 20 AND `event_id` <= 25
ORDER BY $sort $ascdsc
GROUP BY dat_eb_registrants.id
");

Comment: still calling it using: while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) and echo "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>";

Comment: The GROUP BY should probably be before the ORDER BY, but otherwise, that should work.

Comment: it does look like it works a little, but how should i call the values? what $row[?] it assigned to what value??

Comment: ooh i see, when i call $row[9], it fills the table with all of the values correctly but not on the places i want them to be...

Comment: I'm sure you'll get it right with some more fiddling :)
Be sure to accept my answer if it helped you reach you goal ;) (just a friendly suggestion, as I see you're a new member - welcome!)

Answer (score 0):

Voitek Zylinski answer is I think the best way to do this. but you could try a for each.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $row_item)
    {
        echo "<td>".$row_item."</td>"
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

This would work no matter how many field