# MYSQL PHP Output sorting, get values inbetween output

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, while-loop, output

I have a small problem with MySQL tables pushed into a HTML table.

Here is my SELECT on the database:

```
 $result = mysql_query("

SELECT dat_eb_registrants.id, dat_eb_registrants.first_name, dat_eb_registrants.last_name, dat_eb_registrants.email, dat_eb_registrants.comment, dat_eb_registrants.amount, dat_eb_registrants.published, dat_eb_registrants.transaction_id, dat_eb_registrants.register_date, GROUP_CONCAT(dat_eb_field_values.field_value SEPARATOR '</td><td>') 
FROM dat_eb_registrants LEFT JOIN dat_eb_field_values ON dat_eb_registrants.id=dat_eb_field_values.registrant_id
WHERE `event_id` >= 20 AND `event_id` <= 25
GROUP BY dat_eb_registrants.id
ORDER BY $sort $ascdsc

");
```

Which is pushed into my HTML table using this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>";
echo "<td>";
```

Now, my problem is the fact that this fills my table with a few rows from `dat_eb_field_values.field_value`, and I can't get other rows ($row[0] to $row[8]) in-between these results.

For example if my $values come from `dat_eb_field_values.field_value` and my $data comes from `dat_eb_registants`. This would be my table:

```
| header 1 | header 2 | header 3 | header 4 | header 5 | header 6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| $value1  | $value2  | $data3   | $value4  | $data1   | $data2   |
| $value1  | $value2  | $data3   | $value4  | $data1   | $data2   |
| $value1  | $value2  | $data3   | $value4  | $data1   | $data2   |
```

Thanks in advance! Laurent

Comment: just a question, why are you still using mysql_? have you heard of myqsqli_ or PDO?

Comment: yeah, i know it's no good...

Comment: i would recommend using PDO, as it has the widest support for databases include MySQL, SQLite and PostGreSQL. I hope this helps, also prepared statements will prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: ok, i'll take a look into PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing out the data of `$row[9]` place it in a array, then spit it out when you feel it's necessary (and after you've checked for the other elements)

For example change this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>";
echo "<td>";
```

To this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$myArray[] ="<tr><td>" . $row[9] . "</td>""<td>";
```

Comment: Can you maybea give an example? because i don't get how to extract the values from mysql trough an array as it comes from one array...

Comment: ? this gives me a parsing error ? and how can i 'spit' them back out again afterwards? (sorry for all of the questions..)

Comment: not a problem, what i would suggest is to just store $row[9] in the array, and when you spit out the data echo the correct <tr> and <td> tags

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
$myArray[] = $row[9];
echo "<td>"; echo "$myArray[1]"; echo "</td>";

Answer (score 0):

instead of `mysql_fetch_row` use `mysql_fetch_array`

and

`ORDER BY $sort $ascdsc` change it to

```
 ORDER BY '".$sort."', '".$ascdsc."'
```

exemple :
by using `mysql_fetch_array` try echo this

```
  echo $row['dat_eb_registrants.id'] ;
```

your sql is hard to read

use this

```
   SELECT dr.id, dr.first_name, dr.last_name, dr.email, dr.comment, dr.amount, dr.published, dr.transaction_id, dr.register_date, GROUP_CONCAT(df.field_value SEPARATOR '</td><td>') 
   FROM dat_eb_registrants dr 
   LEFT JOIN dat_eb_field_values df 
    ON dr.id=df.registrant_id
   WHERE `event_id` >= 20 AND `event_id` <= 25
   GROUP BY dr.id
   ORDER BY '".$sort."', '".$ascdsc."'
```

but you have accepted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142729/continue-mysql-output-in-php) !!

Comment: Can you maybea give an example? because i don't get how to extract the values from mysql trough an array...

Comment: what's the diff? OP is using numeric keys anyways, and fetch_row returns numeric AND string keys. all you've done is reduced the size of the array returned, but haven't changed anything fundamentally.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't think that is what i mean, what i am trying to do is representing each `field_value` as a new row, so that i can use them seperately. Now it just gives me everything at once.

Comment: this is what i am trying to get: <tr>
  <td>$value1 from dat_eb_registrants</td>
   <td>$value3 from dat_eb_registrants</td>
   <td>$value5 from $row[9] (in dat_eb_field_values)</td>
   <td>$value2 from dat_eb_registrants</td>
   <td>$value4 from $row[9] (in dat_eb_field_values)</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row AS $val)
        echo "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
}
```

that should do